# Textwatcher filtering list

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

I have a problem and it seems like its only me who has it. I have implemented textwatcher and when I filtering a string in listview it's showing the object twice in the list.

This what I'm doing

```
filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

and here is the adapter and textwatcher.

```
        adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(ListBased.this, ListBasedList,
                R.layout.list_item,new String[] 
                       { TAG_Location_Name, TAG_Address, TAG_Dist, TAG_Postal, TAG_Location_id, TAG_City, TAG_Company_id, TAG_Lat, TAG_Lng}, new int[] {
                        R.id.location_name, R.id.location_adress, R.id.dist, R.id.postal, R.id.location_location_id, R.id.location_city, R.id.location_company_id, R.id.lat, R.id.lng});
                    setListAdapter(adapter2);
    }
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() 
{
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter2.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
};
```

its working fine like typed but here is a screenshot how it showing it.

**Screenshot** [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/dp6.png)!

Anyone can explain me the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I figured it out. It is due to you have the same text "Sindal" in name  and city fields of the list.

Comment: yea thats true. it took me time to find out why it was like this. but I have done an adapter which helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: I will try to find it tomorrow and post it as an answer here.